# Why does my Rails page refresh with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm using very basic ajax code in rails, in my /demo view I have this

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: demo_sample_email_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

and it redirects to this method

```
def demo_sample_email
  //do stuff
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to demo_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

From my understanding of Ajax, the /demo page is not supposed to refresh, but I observe that it does, because everything in the page gets refreshed. I inserted the "remote: true" which is supposed to not make it do a refresh.

For my application, I just want to do a `POST` form ajax request that sends information to the server, and nothing back to the browser.

```
　Started POST "/demo_sample_email" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-16 01:14:55 -0700
Processing by StaticPagesController#demo_sample_email as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A60kCDxuItxBanhv02uXIST8kpFdNtWceVQRw13cTE7s/fzo7Z137SxQRxfNpwpAzmUg1lyEm2UD75U5bJeGXA==", "session"=>{"email"=>"blah@blah.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me emails now"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/demo
Completed 302 Found in 79ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/demo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-16 01:14:55 -0700
Processing by StaticPagesController#demo as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/demo.html.erb within layouts/application (85.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (2.6ms)
  User Load (14.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (63.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 533ms (Views: 510.4ms | ActiveRecord: 14.6ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-16 01:14:57 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application.js"):
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:8:in `require'
  bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
  spring (1.1.3) bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
  spring (1.1.3) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/spring:13:in `require'
  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `load'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please post the log.

Comment: Seems like the request made is a `HTML`. Do you have a file with `.js` which is used for performing `ajax`?

Comment: Nope I don't. My understanding (and most likely faulty ) is that Ajax is performed automatically magically through the remote:true call.

Comment: My best guess is you are missing jQuery from your application

Comment: I wait I see...the log says I'm missing an application.js Yep that was the error... for some reason I deleted it accidentally when cleaning things up ><

Comment: But anyhow, if I want nothing back from the browser, I'm still not sure what I should be including in the respond_to block

Comment: @user3916997: "if I want nothing back from the browser" -  this should help `format.js { head :ok }`. Some jquery versions have problems with head-only responses, so an alternative is: `format.js { render json: { status: 'ok' } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `render partial: "your/view", layout: false, locals: {:@foo => @bar}`

which will return a view if you indicate a div to return the ajax response.

You can also render json `format.json { render :json => {:success => true, :html => (render_to_string 'your/view')} }`

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

if your priority is js call and **NOT** HTML call,then change it to..

```
  respond_to do |format|
    ##added .js first and then html,call will come for js,if not then html
    format.js
    format.html { redirect_to demo_path }
  end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do you think this should fix the problem?